# In-app purchase In WINDOWS STORE apps

Tags: c#, windows-8, windows-store-apps, in-app-purchase

We are developing Windows Store application using C#. My application is a News paper application.
   If **User want to purchase(Download) any news paper at that time the In-app purchase will work & after that if user want to download any other paper it have to check the In-app purchase(authentication) again .**
       I searches lot in net & tried MSFT sample, But i didn't get solution which i require.
    Can you suggest me how to implement these type of application.

Comment: What exactly is the problem you're facing? Did you read the MS tutorials on in-app purchases? They explain how to set up individual purchasable items in the developer dashboard and how to use the simulator to develop and debug in-app purchases.

Comment: Is the issue that you want to make each issue of the newspaper its own in-app purchase?

Answer (score 0):

Since you are limited in the number of in-app purchases, you'll want to use a third party provider here. There are several, but one idea is using paypal for the purchases.

http://paypal.github.com/Windows8SDK/